# how to get the median price with two condition

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using  matplotlib.pyplot to return the median price by comparing the housing town and the size of the house by using a bar chart.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        
        labels = list(set(d1['town']))
        levels_values = d1[['town','flat_size','price']]
        price = levels_values['price']
        
        median_values = {}
        
        for i in labels:
            valuesforlevel = price[levels_values['town']==i]
            m = np.median(valuesforlevel)
            median_values[i] = n
```

I am able to find the median price by the housing town, and has difficulty to combine the two conditions to the find the median price of housing town and the size of the house.
How do I combine the two conditions together?

Comment: There's no matplotlib in the code you posted.

Comment: It sounds like you want the median "price" as a function of "town" and "flat_size". If you have discrete flat_sizes that you are considering, with data points in each combination of town and flat_size, then you can just do a double loop over town and flat_size, filter the df using the conjunction of both conditions, and use ***numpy*** to get the median.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I combine the two conditions together?

Whilst working with `pandas.DataFrame` you might use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) to select rows which do meet 2 conditions following way

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5],'y':[5,4,3,2,1]})
df2 = df[np.logical_and(df.x >= 2, df.y >=2)]
print(df2)
```

gives output

```
   x  y
1  2  4
2  3  3
3  4  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'groupby' function in pandas to group the data by both 'town' and 'flat_size' and then calculate the median for each group.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming 'd1' is your DataFrame
labels = list(set(d1['town']))
levels_values = d1[['town', 'flat_size', 'price']]

# Use groupby to group by both 'town' and 'flat_size', and then calculate the median for each group
median_values = levels_values.groupby(['town', 'flat_size'])['price'].median().reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm not allowed to use pandas to solve it. Is there other method?

Comment: @unleasehed, isn't `d1` a pandas dataframe? If so, then you are "using pandas". In either case, you should specify "not allowed to use pandas" and any other constraints in the post ***before*** people waste their time making solutions that aren't acceptable.